# How do you Train a Neural Network in Mini-Batches?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, gradient-descent

I'm currently programming a neural network from scratch in C++.

I'm on the step now where I'm adding the batch logic to the program, and I'm a little confused as to how it works.

So, let's say I have 1000 samples of data, and I'm putting it into batches of 10. In one training epoch, I would feed it 10 samples of data, and then after, run through a sing back-propagation. How would I calculate it's error for that back-propagation? Would I average out it's guesses, and then use that set of values?

Since running through the back propagation and changing it's weights is dependent on the current activation of the neuron, would I just use the values from the last set of data? Or am I thinking of this wrong, and I do propagate backwards after each piece of data in the batch but only adjust weights afterwards?

Here is my function for updating a hidden layer:

```
void Layer::BackProgagate(Layer* previousLayer, Layer* nextLayer, float weightLearningRate, float biasLearningRate, bool adjustValues)
{
    Node* node;
    Node* nextNode;
    Node* previousNode;
    
    for (int n = 0; n < Nodes.size(); n++)
    {
        node = Nodes[n];
        float gamma = 0;

        //Get the gamma value relative to the next layer
        for (int n2 = 0; n2 < nextLayer->Nodes.size(); n2++)
        {
            nextNode = nextLayer->Nodes[n2];

            //foreach neuron in the next layer, add the neuron's gamma times this neurons weight connected to it.
            gamma += nextNode->Gamma * node->Connections[n2];
        }

        gamma *= (1 - node->Value * node->Value);
        node->Gamma = gamma;

        if (!adjustValues)
            return;

        for (int n2 = 0; n2 < previousLayer->Nodes.size(); n2++)
        {
            previousNode = previousLayer->Nodes[n2];

            //Calculate a New Value to Subtract
            float Delta = gamma * previousNode->Value;

            //Apply the New Value to Adjust the Weight thats pointing to the neuron
            previousNode->Connections[n] -= Delta * weightLearningRate;

            //Apply the New Value to Adjust the Bias of the Previous Weight
            previousNode->Bias -= Delta * biasLearningRate;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my function for updating an output layer:

```
void Layer::BackPropagate(Layer* previousLayer, std::vector<float> desiredAnswer, float weightLearningRate, float biasLearningRate, bool adjustValues)
{
    Node* node;
    Node* nextNode;
    Node* previousNode;

    for (int n = 0; n < Nodes.size(); n++)
    {
        node = Nodes[n];
        float gamma = 0;

        gamma = (node->Value - desiredAnswer[n]);

        gamma *= (1 - node->Value * node->Value);

        node->Gamma = gamma;

        if (!adjustValues)
            return;

        for (int n2 = 0; n2 < previousLayer->Nodes.size(); n2++)
        {
            previousNode = previousLayer->Nodes[n2];

            //Calculate a New Value to Subtract
            float Delta = gamma * previousNode->Value;

            //Apply the New Value to Adjust the Weight thats pointing to the neuron
            previousNode->Connections[n] -= Delta * weightLearningRate;

            //Apply the New Value to Adjust the Bias of the Previous Weight
            previousNode->Bias -= Delta * biasLearningRate;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the function to train the network:

```
void NeuralNetwork::TrainNetwork(std::vector<float> desiredAnswer)
{
    Layer* layer;

    float MSE = (pow(OutputLayer()->Nodes[0]->Value - desiredAnswer[0], 2) / 2) + (pow(OutputLayer()->Nodes[1]->Value - desiredAnswer[1], 2) / 2);
    std::cout << "MSE: " << MSE << "\n";

    //Iterate from the output layer to every layer except the inputs.
    for (int l = Layers.size() - 1; l > 0; l--)
    {
        layer = Layers[l];
        
        if (layer == OutputLayer())
            layer->BackPropagate(Layers[l - 1], desiredAnswer, weightLearningRate, biasLearningRate, false);
        else
            layer->BackProgagate(Layers[l - 1], Layers[l + 1], weightLearningRate, biasLearningRate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Or am I thinking of this wrong, and I do propagate backwards after each piece of data in the batch but only adjust weights afterwards?

The correct implementation is to compute all the backpropagation **separately for each data point** and then average the result, which comes from linearity of the gradient operator:

```
GRAD 1/N SUM_i f_i = 1/N SUM_i GRAD f_i
```

In other words: gradient of an average is an average of the gradients.